# View image in fullscreen transition same as Facebook app in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, animation, uiimageview

I want to make the transition when touch on image to open the fullscreen same as Facebook app. When user touch on image, the transition is push down image to center, user touch on image again, it will back to previous page. How can i do that? For now, I have 1 viewcontroller contains the imageview in center. I used the code below to make animation when push viewcontroller but it seems not correct.

This is my code :

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.5;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionFromTop; //kCATransitionMoveIn; //, kCATransitionPush, kCATransitionReveal, kCATransitionFade
//transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop; //kCATransitionFromLeft, kCATransitionFromRight, kCATransitionFromTop, kCATransitionFromBottom
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
```

[self.navigationController pushViewController:imageView animated:NO];

Please give me some advices. Thanks.